# Unable to locate element inside Gmail

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I've created a project using Nightwatch.js. The process performs checks in our dev enviroment (which works just fine) and will end up sending a test email to a Gmail account. The process will then go to Gmail, login and click the correct email.

I am attempting to get the URL that was sent to the application (a forgot password link) and sending the browser to the correct URL.

The issue is when I use the following code:

```
browser
  .useXpath()
  .getText("string(//*[text()[contains(text(),'RetrievePassword')]])",function(result)
  {
    console.log(result.log)
  })
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: Unable to locate element "" using: xpath

But when I tell Nightwatch to click the link, it will do so with no issue.  Any idea?

The URL looks like this:

https://test.website.com/Secure/RetrievePassword.aspx?code=123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your XPath selector is wrong. If you use `//*[contains(text(),'RetrievePassword')]` instead, it should work. Here is a basic example:

**HTML** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nightwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="https://test.website.com/Secure/RetrievePassword.aspx?code=123456789">https://test.website.com/Secure/RetrievePassword.aspx?code=123456789</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (*gmail.js*)

```
module.exports = {
  'Gmail': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/index.html') // Change this if needed
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
      .useXpath()
      .getText("//*[contains(text(),'RetrievePassword')]", function (res) {
        console.log(res.value);
      })
      .end();
  }
};
```

**Command**

```
nightwatch -t tests/gmail.js
```